# How do I get the values printed to LOGFILE to be stored in arrays

Tags: c, arrays, parsing, command-line

```
int parse_command_line (char commandLine[MAX_INPUT_LINE_LENGTH], char* cmds[MAX_CMDS_NUM]){
  char delims[] = "|";
  char *result = NULL;
  result = strtok( commandLine, delims );
 int count = 0;

  if((logfp=fopen("LOGFILE", "w"))==NULL)
    {
      perror("Error");
      exit(1);


  while( result != NULL ) {
    fprintf(logfp, "cmd[%d] will point to string \"%s\"\n", count, result);
    count=count+1;
    result = strtok( NULL, delims );
  }
  fclose(logfp);


  //exit(1);
}
```

The fprintf statement puts the line terminated by the delim "|" into LOGFILE.  I want that value to also be stored in an array which I can access in the process that follows.  Each time a line is added to LOGFILE, I need that value in an array.

Comment: cmd is the array that it needs to be stored.. I understand that it hasnt been initialized yet.  How do I initialize cmd as an array that can hold each line as the function iterates through the command line inputs to parse through them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do, just add

```
cmds[count] = result;
```

after the `fprintf()` and before `count=count+1;`

Comment: Thank you sir.  I knew that is was simple. Just didnt want to create a bigger issue than I needed.